# What are efficient methods for classifying tremor intensity, given challenges with 3D CNN and memory issues with a pretrained VideoMAE model?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, python

I have a training dataset of 80 videos (without augmentation). They are 15 seconds video recorded at 30fps and 240*480 dimensions. What options do I have to train a classification model? The problem statement is I have videos of people with tremor. I want to classify the intensity of tremor on the scale of 1 - 3. Please suggest some ways to work with this

I have tried using 3D CNN but it requires excessive compute power. I also tried to train the model by fine-tuning pretrained VideoMAE model from huggingface but it only accepts 16 frames instead of 450 frames (15s * 30fps). I tried to change the arch but then it gives me memory error.